# Partial Derivatives Calculus

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, partial-derivative, implicit-differentiation

If $$x^x\cdot y^y\cdot z^z=c$$ then prove that $$\frac{\partial^2z}{\partial x \, \partial y}=(-x\log_ex)^{-1}$$
How to do this?
I was first taking logarithm and then differentiating but did not work.

Comment: Use implicit function theorem.

Comment: What is that? Can you solve it